# How to find data from rets using mls number in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rets

I'm using rets gem in ruby on rails api for getting data from mls.I'm try to getting Data using MlsNum In query. Here is my code:

```
result = clientobj.find :all, {
    search_type: "property",
    class: "CommercialProperty",
    query: "(MLNUM=|W4214585)"
}
```

But it gives me this error:

```
MLS feed: Got error code 20200 (Unknown Query Field)
```

Please help me I'm stuck for a day it's important for me.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please provide full request call in your question.

Example: 
`property = client.find :first, {
  search_type: 'Property',
  class: 'CLASS_NAME',
  query: 'RETS_QUERY',
  limit: 1
}`

Comment: Hii Oleksii ,I want access the data from mls number. I'm giving MLNUM in query but it gives me error code 20200 .

Comment: I can only give you few recommendations.

Comment: 1. This gem is quite outdated. Even link to rest.org in it description redirected to new website reso.org, which have more fresh ruby repo in [documentation](https://www.reso.org/web-api-tools/).

2. If you still need this old resource, try to dig in to understand where  the problem is. First of all who gives this error - external API (you can tru with curl) or ruby code? If external API: is `client` object you use connected to API? Also try to find their docs and check how to build query.

Comment: Can anyone help me how to get all mls data from query without giving any property type in query.Right Now I am giving like this : result = clientObj.find :all, {
   search_type: "Property",
     class: "",
      query: "Status|=A"
  }

Comment: @Priyadarshanimini, I'm not aware of any MLS that will allow you to query without the class so you get can multiple property types in one go. Some MLS's will provide a "Multi" class that combines data for multiple property types for this purpose, but if the one you are connecting to doesn't have this, you're probably out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
result = clientobj.find :all, {
    search_type: "Property",
    class: "CommercialProperty",
    query: "(MLNUM=W4214585)"
}
```

also help this link https://retsmd.com/ login with your api details.

Comment: Is the only difference the casing of `"Property"`? Explain your thinking behind the answer please...

Comment: Yes. you have to give specific class as per your api like 'Property', 'Media', 'Office'

Comment: Holy cow, was that link to retsmd.com every helpful! THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try your query like this,

```
query: "(MLNUM=W4214585)"
```

Just ensure the field name is spelled correctly ('MLNUM' itself or something else)

I just removed the pipe symbol ("|") from the query.